# TextArea Box Removes Text When Clicked On? How To Stop This?

Tags: html

Example URL: http://moviepostersdb.com/the-host/poster-1

On the above page on the right hand side under "Poster Embed Code" I have a text area that is support to have an image embed code.

My problem is that whenever someone clicks in the box to copy/paste, all the text currently entered is removed. When they click away, it re-appears.

From looking at the code below; does anyone see why this is happening?

```
<form action="#">
<fieldset>
<textarea cols="37" rows="2"><a href="www.link.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.moviepostersdb.com/<?php echo $poster['image_large']; ?>" width="600"    height="890" border="0" alt="<?php echo $movie['movie_name']; ?> 
<?php echo $poster['poster_name']; ?>" />
 </a></textarea>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "main.js" file has a function that clears all textareas upon focus,

```
function initInputs() {
PlaceholderInput.replaceByOptions({
    // filter options
    clearInputs: true,
    **clearTextareas: true**,
    clearPasswords: true,
    skipClass: 'default',

    // input options
    wrapWithElement: false,
    showUntilTyping: false,
    getParentByClass: false,
    placeholderAttr: 'value'
});
}
```

This is causing the issue. You may want to remove that line.

Comment: This worked perfect. It was setup like this for the search bar but obviously a wrong setting had been set. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

You placeholder class in main.js is causing this.